# Calling 3 recursions in one line?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ programming, and a while ago I started learning recursion functions. So my question is, can be this done with recursion?

```
u(n)=n*u(n-1)+(n+1)*u(n-2)+n
```

Comment: Short answer: Yes. What are the end-points? (How does the recursion finish?)

Comment: Recursive functions are not magical. They are just functions that happen to call themselves in some (not all!) cases. Call them wherever you like.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be done, however that will have exponential complexity. A better way is to compute bottom up and cache lower values of u as you proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, provided you handle the base case correctly. The function as it stands is not fully defined: you need to explicitly state the values of `u(0)` and `u(1)` (or whatever else the base case may be).

Note that the function calls itself *twice* (with `n-1` and `n-2`), and not three times as the title of your question suggests.

Also, in this particular case the recursion is unnecessary and suboptimal: you could simply use two variables for keeping two most recent numbers, and proceed iteratively. For a discussion of different approaches, see [ICS 161: Design and Analysis of Algorithms: Fibonacci Numbers](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960109.html); the functional form there is different, but all of the discussion applies to your function.

Comment: Maybe he's missing one `u`: u(n)=n*u(n-1)+ **u** (n+1)*u(n-2)+n

Comment: @LihO: That would be an unfortunate recursive call.

Comment: @LihO: In case you do not see the reason for Greg's comment, if your recursion goes both *up* and *down* (i.e. `u(n-1)` and `u(n+1)`) you are going to run into an infinite loop: you start in `N`, then jump to `{ N+1, N-1 }`, if you pick the first one, it will recurse into `N+1-1` and `N+1+1`, the first of which is `N` or the original case, causing infinite recursion and most probably a *StackOverflow*

Comment: i understand waht you mean, i thought it could be better resolving it recuselvly. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: And what do you think I meant with that *"I know"* I wrote just now ?

Comment: @LihO: :) the comment was not showing in my browser (loaded the page before your last comment was added)